# How to display inverted vertical slider?

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-8

How can I invert a vertical slider control so that the minimum is at the top, and the maximum at the bottom? If I rotate it by 180 degrees about the z-axis then it unfortunately inverts the text in the labels too.

I'm aware of an ugly workaround I can use by giving it a custom LabelFormatter and mapping the values in code but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well I had to go with the workaround. Bidirectionally bind to the negation of the slider's value, min and max properties, and work with those bound properties instead. Just remember to cross over the max and min properties. Also set a label formatter that negates the value before conversion to string.